# How to get default value for Formtastic date / time select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

I am using Formtastic 1.2.3. I want the current date and time already to be selected when the form is loaded. I tried many combinations with `:default` or `:selected`, but none worked. Even from the github page of Formtastic I can't get information on that. Any suggestions? Thanks for your time!

```
= form.input :date,:hint => 'Select a date',
             :prompt => {:day => "Day", :month => "Month", :year => "Year"},
             :start_year => Time.now.year
= form.input :time
```

Comment: any luck on figuring out the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this by setting the value in the active record object directly when it's created like so:

In the model class:

```
def after_initialize
  self.start_time ||= Time.now
end
```

Then when the form is displayed, it will already have the time populated and set correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Using `after_initialize` to set a default value for a form is too heavy-handed. What about cases when blank values are acceptable? This is the responsibility of the controller, not the model.

```
class ResourceController < ApplicationController
  def new
    # do stuff
    @resource.important_date ||= Time.zone.today
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax looks alright and it should work (works for me). You might want to add the :as => :date constraint as well just in case.

```
form.input :date, :as => :date, :hint => 'Select a date',
         :prompt => {:day => "Day", :month => "Month", :year => "Year"},
         :start_year => Time.now.year
```

I found this [discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/formtastic/browse_thread/thread/37fa9af263283cf1) on Google Groups, where Justin French discusses the same. Maybe that will also help.

Comment: The `:as => :date` option has been deprecated -- use `:as => :date_select` now

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Jeriko. Using an `after_initialize` just begs for trouble. Another option if you do not have access to the controller (or don't want to access it) is to do something like this:

```
(f.object.received_on = Time.zone.today) unless f.object.received_on.present?
```

I needed to do this to initialize an Active Admin form where I don't want to access the controller and definitely don't want to touch the model.